# Ubuntu Could not purge package

Tags: ubuntu, apt, dpkg, aptitude

I've tried to install **oracle-java7-installer** package from custom repository onto Ubuntu 12. It was failed during executing some post-installation script.
So. I want just to rollback it and proceed with another solutions (to install java 7 jdk).
I've tried to make

UPDATED with **set -x**

```
 >  sudo aptitude remove oracle-java7-installer
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  oracle-java7-installer
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 47 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 82.9 kB will be freed.
(Reading database ... 61748 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing oracle-java7-installer ...
+ uname -m
+ arch=amd64
+ dld=x64
+ J_INSTALL_DIR=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
+ [ remove = remove ]
+ [ -d /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/man/man1 ]
+ basename /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/*
+ name=*
+ [ ! -f /usr/bin/* -o -L /usr/bin/* ]
+ update-alternatives --remove bin boot dev etc home initrd.img lib lib64 lost+found media mnt opt proc raid root run sbin selinux srv sys tmp usr var vmlinuz /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/*
update-alternatives: error: unknown argument `dev'
dpkg: error processing oracle-java7-installer (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Downloading...
--2012-10-24 17:53:33--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u3-b04/jdk-7u3-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 80.239.148.219, 80.239.148.216
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|80.239.148.219|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u3-b04/jdk-7u3-linux-x64.tar.gz [following]
--2012-10-24 17:53:33--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u3-b04/jdk-7u3-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 2.22.42.174
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|2.22.42.174|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://download.oracle.com/errors/download-fail-1505220.html [following]
--2012-10-24 17:53:33--  http://download.oracle.com/errors/download-fail-1505220.html
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|80.239.148.219|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 5307 (5.2K) [text/html]
Saving to: `./jdk-7u3-linux-x64.tar.gz'

     0K .....                                                 100%  466M=0s

2012-10-24 17:53:33 (466 MB/s) - `./jdk-7u3-linux-x64.tar.gz' saved [5307/5307]

Download done.
sha256sum mismatch jdk-7u3-linux-x64.tar.gz
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java7-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
```

```
> sudo aptitude search oracle-java7-installer
   Cd  oracle-java7-installer                                                 - Sun Java(TM) Development Kit (JDK) 7
```

What I can do with that? Is it possible to rollback to the previous state without trying to deinstall broken package??

So. I understand from output that scripts inside package are wrong. they failed to download tar.gz from Oracle site and failed to install due to that. Also it does not handle properly **remove** commande and trying to install it again when I want to remove package. The basic question - is it possible to just rollback that package without running scripts? F.e. like in windows "System restore"? Or I should do this manually?

P.S.

> lsb_release -a
>           No LSB modules are available.
>           Distributor ID: Ubuntu
>           Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
>           Release:        12.04
>           Codename:       precise

P.P.S

> sh -x /var/lib/dpkg/info/oracle-java7-installer.prerm
>          + set -e
>          + uname -m
>          + arch=amd64
>          + dld=x64
>          + J_INSTALL_DIR=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
>          + [  = remove ]
>          + [  = deconfigure ]
>          + exit 0

Comment: Run the following (as root) and provide the output so we can see why prerm is failing: `sh -x /var/lib/dpkg/info/oracle-java7-installer.prerm`

Comment: It looks like the error won't occur unless the remove or deconfigure condition is met. Edit the file, and add `set -x` under `set -e`. Run the `aptitude remove` again and update the output in your question.

Comment: @jordanm updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That package appears to be buggy and of poor quality. The way to work around the buggy code in the maintainer scripts is to simply replace them with a noop script that will return true.

Replace `/var/lib/dpkg/info/oracle-java7-installer.prerm` and `/var/lib/dpkg/info/oracle-java7-installer.postrm` with the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
exit 0
```

You should be able to remove the packages once the buggy maintainer scripts are replaced.